# Neo4j Cypher- Equivalent of ADD_DATE(date,INTERVAL expr unit)

Tags: sql, neo4j, cypher

I have some sql queries that I want to translate to cypher. One of my queries contains the function DATE_ADD :

```
WHERE s_date<=DATE_ADD('2000-12-01',INTERVAL -90 DAY);
```

Is there any equivalent function in cypher please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use APOC for that : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_adding_subtracting_time_unit_values_to_timestamps

Or if you are using the temporal feature of Neo4j 3.4, you can add a `Duration` to a `Date` : `RETURN date({year:2018, month:3, day: 31}) + duration('P1D')`.

For more information, see the documentation : https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-specifying-durations

Cheers